# Email sending in asp.net without authentication

Tags: asp.net, email, authentication

I want to send email in `asp.net` web application without authentication, that means without having to enter the password by the email sender just like in contact page of a normal website. Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could provide an example of what you would like to do. I have something, but I'm not sure if it would fit your case. In my case, I am sending an email from a secondary gmail account to my primary gmail account and the user does not have to provide the authentication.

Comment: If the UseDefaultCredentials property is set to false and the Credentials property has not been set, then mail is sent to the server anonymously.

Comment: @Trey50Daniel yes i have an application where customer asks their query through email.All their mails need to be send to my primary gmail account i.e; info@something.com without need to type their passwords beside they just need to type their name and drop message or might be email id too .Can you help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @PrabhatSinha Thank you friend but it didnt help.

Comment: @SanzayShakya Do they need to send an email like it is sending from their email or just from any email to your email? I.e., can it be any email as long as their message is sent to your email? Or do you need to have it sent from their email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your e-mail provider, like gmail, demands authentication, you cannot "send email without authentication".

Each and every contact form you will find on the Internet for sure will do some backend stuff for sending emails, including authentication against the SMTP.

Create an account for that purpose, and use those credentials.